# PHP multiply Two fields

Tags: php

I am trying to multiply to fields together to obtain a total in PHP form.

```
   <label for="190_mnth2"></label>
          <div align="center">
            <input name="190_mnth" type="text" id="190_mnth2" value="10" size="5" />
          </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
          <label for="190_rate"></label>
          <input name="190_rate" type="text" id="190_rate" value="190.00" size="10" />
        </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
          <input name="total_190" type="text" id="total_190" value=<? echo '190_mnth2' * '190_rate' ?> size="10" />
```

The above is my current code but the answer is totally wrong it gives me 36100 What is wrong with my formula if anyone can assist?

Comment: `'190_mnth2'` is a string literal. When you use it for multiplication, it's been evaluated as 190.

Comment: You are just doing it wrong. PHP can NOT evaluate expressions like that: When the third field is created, the first 2 have not been filled by the user (Cause this all happens before the user even sees the fields)... Please Review some tutorials on sending and Evaluation data. Explaining Basics is not the purpose of stack Overflow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all you cannot calculate the total like that, it's not Javascript, you need a form with a get/post request which will send a request to the server, server will process and throw the calculated value back to the user.. so wrap the fields around forms, set your method to post(preferred) and than you can write your PHP code like

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit_button_name'])) { //Use $_GET if it's a GET request
       //Save the values in variable
       $mnth_190 = $_POST['190_mnth']; 
       $rate_190 = $_POST['190_rate'];

       //Calculate here
       $total = $mnth_190 * $rate_190;

       /* Now you can use $total either to echo straight in your page, 
      or inside another input field */
   }
?>
```

Also make sure you validate the data before the form is posted and is calculated, check whether the user input doesn't have string or any other special character.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of PHP is to generate HTML to display, not to update the HTML of the current page. You can create a POST request that submits your data for display on another page. If you want to dynamically update the total on the current page, you should use Javascript or another front end language.

Answer (score 0):

```
<? echo '190_mnth2' * '190_rate' ?>
```

You're attempting to multiply two strings, which will probably be converted by PHP as 190 * 190.

In order to get this to work, you're going to have to do it in two separate steps (with PHP anyway). Because PHP is a server side language, you'll have to $_POST[''], or submit these two values as part of the query string and use $_GET[''] to calculate.

If you don't want to do it this way, then I'd suggest looking at some JavaScript to handle it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a shot at doing something like this, as an example.

```
$190_mnth2 = 10;
$190_rate = 190;

$total = $190_mnth2 * $190_rate;
```

then using: `value=<? echo '$total'; ?>`